# Oja learning rule

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network

I'm trying to implement Oja's learning rule to my Hopfield network.
I'm basing on this: http://wiki.eyewire.org/en/Oja%27s_rule
For now I'm trying to do like this:
create base matrix of weights:

```
def matrix_preparation(input_patterns):
    n = len(input_patterns)
    num_neurons = len(input_patterns[0])
    weights = np.zeros((num_neurons, num_neurons))
    for i in range(num_neurons):
        for j in range(num_neurons):
            # if i == j:
            #     continue
            for m in range(n):
                weights[i, j] += input_patterns[m][i] * input_patterns[m][j]
    weights /= n
    return weights
```

Then I use this function in Oja's training:

```
def oja_training(network, input_patterns):
    """Ucz sieć metodą Oja"""
    u = 0.8  # współczynnik prędkości uczenia

    n = len(input_patterns)
    num_neurons = network.get_weights().shape[0]
    weights = matrix_preparation(input_patterns)

    for i in range(num_neurons):  # i do kogo wchodzi
        for j in range(num_neurons):  # j od kogo wychodzi
            if i == j:
                continue
            for pattern in input_patterns:
                V = 0.0
                for k, signal in enumerate(pattern):
                    V += signal * weights[i, k]
                weights[i, j] += u * V * (pattern[i] - V * weights[i, j])
```

The problem is that I'm getting:
1.Lot of NaNs if u > 0.01
2.Not working net, if u < 0.01. I mean: there is no result, blank pattern

Anyone could help me implement Oja's learning rule correctly?

Comment: decrease learning rate!

Comment: i am not sure ,but, it seems that you have not de-centralized the input_data.